# Mocking a component method with Jest

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs

I have a react component that uses `fetch` to talk to an API, it looks like this

```
class Customer extends Component {
  loadCustomer(id) {
    fetch(API + '/customers/' + id)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((js) => {
       this.update(js);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to write jest tests for it like this

```
jest.mock(Customer, () => {loadCustomer: jest.fn()});

describe('Customer', () => {
  it('renders customer', async  () => {
    const ret = `
    // sample json from the API
    `
    const result = Promise.resolve(ret);
    const tree = renderer.create(
      <Customer customerId={125}/>
    );
    loadCustomer.mockImplementation(() => result);
    await result;
    expect(tree.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

This fails with

```
 FAIL  tests/Customer.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/Customer.test.js:12:48)
```

The offending line being
`jest.mock(Customer, () => {loadCustomer: jest.fn()});`

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**
If I change the offending line to 
`jest.mock(Customer, () => ({loadCustomer: jest.fn()}));`
I get

```
FAIL  tests/Customer.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/Customer.test.js:12:48)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

**EDIT**
If I mock the `fetch` method like this

```
beforeEach(() => {
  global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve({
        json: function() {
          return { // some json }
        }
     return p;
    });
  });
});

describe('Customer', () => {
  it('renders customer', async () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(
      <Customer customerId={125}/>
    ).toJSON();
    await tree;
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Then the test does not wait for the fetch to complete.

Comment: You return nothing in your mocked customer.
Try `jest.mock(Customer, () => ({loadCustomer: jest.fn()}));`

Comment: This does not work as `jest.mock` expects a string which is the path to a module, which then is replaced by the the result of the function which is the second parameter. Why you want to mock a function in the component anyway. It would be better to just mock `fetch`.

Comment: Thanks, that did solve the problem. I did try to mock global fetch in a `beforeEach` block. But how do I wait for the async fetch call to complete in the `it` function?

Comment: @AndreasKöberle I added my attempt at mocking the global fetch function!

Comment: Ah, I see the problem, its solvable.

Answer (score 0):

The problm when mocking fetch is that it returns a promise, but your test does not wait for or return this promise, have a look at this [part of the docs](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/asynchronous.html#promises) to understand the problem.

```
var p
beforeEach(() => {
  var p = Promise.resolve({
    json: () => ({}),
  })
  global.fetch = () => p
});

describe('Customer', () => {
  it('renders customer', async () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(
      <Customer customerId={125} />,
    ).toJSON();
    await p;
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

So you need to create the promise and store it in a variable, so you can then wait for it in your test.

Comment: Thanks but that does not seem to work. I have a text block that is shown while it's loading data and I get that in my snapshot.